# deparse vector of fractions, keeping the fractions

Tags: r

Is there a way to use `deparse` to return a string with the original fractions? Default behavior shown below:

```
> deparse(c(1/2, 2/3, 3))
[1] "c(0.5, 0.666666666666667, 3)"
```

Desired result `"c(1/2, 2/3, 3)"`

Similarly with a list:

```
> deparse(list("name", 1/2, 2/3))
[1] "list(\"name\", 0.5, 0.666666666666667)"
```

Desired result `"list(\"name\", 1/2, 2/3)"`

EDIT:

Some more detail about the input. The user may provide "1/2 2/3 3" for example. After some parsing I use `MASS::fractions` to convert to a vector or fractions.

```
x <- c(1/2, 2/3, 3)
x <- MASS::fractions(x)
deparse(x, control = "keepNA")
```

```
Result: "c(0.5, 0.666666666666667, 3)"
Desired result "c(1/2, 2/3, 3)"
```

I'm looking for a way to tell deparse to use the fraction notation or else a way to prep the vector before passing to deparse so I get the desire result. From the responses so far (thanks all!) it seems this may be difficult

Comment: do you need to use only `deparse` ? This is easy with `substitute` actually. `substitute(c(1/2, 2/3, 3))`

Comment: I do need `deparse` in my application but otherwise `substitute` does seem to work as intended.

Comment: Your input is unclear. If your input is the evaluated numeric vector (as shown) there is nothing you can do. If the input is not evaluated yet, there are several options but you need to provide a specific example of how that input is provided.

Comment: @Roland I updated information about the input. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Check if MASS has a format method for this class. If yes, use it.

Comment: However, you won't get the call to c. That call is already evaluated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `deparse(quote(c(1/2, 2/3, 3)))`.

`quote` will first quote the expression which will tell the intent then deparse will intern change into  character strings

**Output**:

```
> deparse(quote(c(1/2, 2/3, 3)))
[1] "c(1/2, 2/3, 3)"
```

**Hackish way:**

```
 x = alist(x = c(1/2, 2/3, 3))
 deparse(x$x)
```

**?alist:**

> alist handles its arguments as if they described function arguments.
>   So the values are not evaluated, and tagged arguments with no value
>   are allowed whereas list simply ignores them. alist is most often used
>   in conjunction with formals.

**Output**:

```
     > deparse(x$x)
[1] "c(1/2, 2/3, 3)"
```

Comment: This looks great. Is there a way to do this with the following as well? `tmp <- c(1/2, 2/3, 3); deparse(quote(tmp))`

Comment: @Vincent, hmm.. I don't think so, it will immediately get evaluated if you write this: `tmp <- c(1/2, 2/3, 3)` and hit enter, then the evaluated  "c(0.5, 0.666666666666667, 3)" will be saved if you use deparse further. There is a hackish way i can think of. Updated the answer

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `fractions()` function from the MASS package.  For example,

```
library(MASS)
tmp <- c(1/2, 2/3, 3)
fractions(tmp)
# [1] 1/2 2/3   3
```

If you really want it in the `c(1/2, 2/3, 3)` form, use `paste`:

```
paste0("c(", paste(fractions(tmp), collapse = ", "), ")")
# [1] "c(1/2, 2/3, 3)"
```

Comment: I ended up using your approach in my application but PKumar's response addressed my initial question.